# new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT, ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI); is not working in Some of the devices like Oppo, Galaxy J7-6.0.0

Tags: android, crash-reports

Hello Below the code to go in contact edit page is working fine in all the devices but it is not working in some of devices.
Please help me.

```
   Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT, ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI);
    startactivity(intent1)
```

Below is the report of google prelaunch application test.

[image]

Comment: I am not aware that there is a requirement for any Android device to support that particular `Intent` structure. Frankly, I am surprised that any device supports it.

Comment: Even I am surprised in the oppo, Even application is not crashing. And it is working in all other phones.

Answer (score 1):

This things is not working in below devices as per the Alpha Prelaunch test

[image]