# Should I believe in google app crash report because same things are working in real device

Tags: android, crash, google-console-developer

I have published my application in alpha testing.
Google console showing the google app crash report.

It shows one error in few devices.

Application crash is in this line

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT, ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI);
```

Error log is- 
 "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSERT dat=content://com.android.contacts/profile }"

and also one thing to note that here it is working in lolipop devices but it crashes in above the lolipop version

but i am not facing that error in real devices. but I am faces that error in simulator.

as I don't have all real devices  to test the application
So if you [image]have any experience like this please share with me so I can get more  idea.

So i can take decision to upload in live or not.

Comment: Please add the complete error log. As Android emulator cannot handle some actions.

Comment: "No activity found to handle Intent(..." - well, that's where it gets interesting. You seem to start an Activity (with which kind of Intent action?) and the devices where the crashes occurs do not have any Activity which can handle this specific Intent action. To be on the safe side, [always use resolveActivity()](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/JUGR3bXGDoM). For more info take a look at this [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGElAW224dE)

Comment: I have edited my question description.
This is the log - android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSERT dat=content://com.android.contacts/profile }

Answer (score 1):

Google runs its prelaunch report test on a datacenter full of real devices, not just on emulators. So if the crash happens on the pre-launch report test, it can happen on real devices in the wild. So yes, you should believe it.

Google also picks some of the most common real world devices to test on, so if happens on the prelaunch report it could happen for millions of real world users.

Comment: Hey Can you help me for this 

[URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330091/new-intentintent-action-edit-contactscontract-profile-content-uri-is-not-wor)

Is there any way to fix it.?